# I am not able to switch to IFrame using Internet Explorer

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-8

I have developed a s keyword driven framework. It has a action keyword to switch the frame.
It works fine with Mozilla. But when it comes to IE it is not switching. It logs error.
IE driver -IEDriverServer_x64_2.44.0
IE version -9
Selenium version -selenium-java-2.44.0

Thanks in advance.

```
public static void switchFrame(String object,String data)throws Exception{
        try{
        driver.switchTo().frame("Ifrm");
        Log.info("Switched the frame");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.error("Not able to switch the frame--- " + e.getMessage());
            DriverScript.bResult = false;
        }
    }
```

Here exception occurs.

Comment: Can you post the code and line at which it throws error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the value you specified in frame is id/name/etc.  You have to access the frame by calling the driver with specified value. Code would be

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("Ifrm")));
```

Comment: 2015-02-27 16:44:22,954 ERROR [Log] Not able to switch the frame--- Unable to find element with id == Ifrm (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Issue persist

Comment: Can you post the HTML code or Screenshot in IE and Firefox ? . As frame name may differ between IE and Firefox. Also compare both IE and Firefox DOM structure. There might be additional frames in IE. Is the website public accessible , if so specify .I will try .

Comment: No. can you give your mail ID?

Comment: I guess you can add screen shot/attachment here itself. Hope it's not policy violation of sharing email id. My email id is visitjaga@gmail.com .

Comment: Seems to still be failing, you can switch by numeric IDs, but not by WebElement or by ID name

Answer (score 0):

Selenium won't let me switch to the `iframe` by ID on Internet Explorer, but it does allow me to switch by index.  If you have some sort of property that you can check that it is only available on the `iframe` you can do the following

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
  new Predicate<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(WebDriver input) {
      try {
        int i = 1;
        while (true) {
          driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
          driver.switchTo().frame(i);
          String aClass =
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body"))
                  .getAttribute("class");
          if (aClass.contains("modal")) {
            return true;
          }
          ++i;
        }
      } catch (NoSuchFrameException e) {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In my case I was looking for a `body` class of `modal`